# Determine ActualHeight of a StackPanel of Grids in code-behind with IsSharedSizeScope applied

Tags: c#, wpf, issharedsizescope

I am trying to determine the dimensions needed to display a collection of items in its entirety -- but without having rendered it on the screen.

In most cases, we have a known/fixed width but need to dynamically change the height. The strategy thus far has been to instantiate similar controls in code-behind, set the width, invoke Measure/Arrange, and then use the resulting ActualHeight. This (smelly) strategy has been working relatively well, but it seems to be falling apart when I try to use grid shared size scopes.

This code, in theory, should tell me the height I need to display multiple items in a StackPanel:

```
var panel = new StackPanel();
Grid.SetIsSharedSizeScope(panel, true);
panel.Width = this.Width;

foreach (var item in this.Items)
{
    var presenter = new ContentPresenter
    {
        Content = item,
        ContentTemplate = <<code to fetch the data template resource>>
    };

    panel.ApplyTemplate();
    panel.Children.Add(presenter);
}

// this doesn't seem to help: panel.UpdateLayout();
panel.Measure(new Size(this.Width, Double.PositiveInfinity));
panel.Arrange(new Rect(panel.DesiredSize));

return panel.ActualHeight;
```

The data template definitely makes use of the shared size groups:

```
<DataTemplate ...>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MedCol0" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MedCol1" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MedCol2" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MedCol3" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding StartDate}" />
    ...
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding Comments}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
</DataTemplate>
```

And when it's presented on the UI via XAML, it works fine too:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" ItemsSource="..." ItemTemplate="..." />
```

It simply doesn't work in the code-behind when I build a panel by hand to evaluate ActualHeight before anything gets rendered to the screen.

For whatever reason, when I set a breakpoint and watch the ActualWidth of each grid column, they vary row by row. I don't know why the shared size scope doesn't work in this code. Any ideas? Do I need to invoke some other WPF method for updating layout?

Comment: The reasoning behind this wacky implementation is that we've created a drag-and-drop report designer where we bind and serialize the Canvas.Top, Canvas.Left, Width, and Height of each item. The layout was intended to be static. However, the previous special case of dynamically-expanding items has somehow become the norm. We have to manually displace content, as well as wrap text, collections, and tables to following pages. Yikes. Ideally, this whole system would be implemented with FlowDocuments instead.

Comment: At which point do you check in debugger column widths? Your code works fine when I use as part of some visual tree, for example `Window.Content`. Since you say you can check widths of columns in `DataTemplate` it would suggest that you use that `panel` somewhere

Comment: @dkozl With a breakpoint at `return panel.Height;`, evaluating `((Grid)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild((ContentPresenter)panel.Children[0], 0)).ColumnDefinitions[0].ActualWidth` yields the width of the first row's first column. However, when I change `Children[0]` to `Children[1]` or any other number, the resulting ActualWidth is different. e.g. I have 137, 105, and 49, but I'd expect them all to be 137.

Comment: It won't give you correct value until you'll use that panel somewhere. [`FrameworkElement.ActualWidth`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualwidth(v=vs.110).aspx): _This property is a calculated value based on other width inputs, and the layout system. The value is set by the layout system itself, based on an actual rendering pass ..._

Comment: @dkozl calling `panel.Measure(...)` and `panel.Arrange(...)` has provided me with an accurate ActualHeight value in other situations, and I believe it is a valid alternative to actually rendering the control on-screen. However, I did try `var window = new Window() { Content = panel };` and `window.Show()` and ended up with the same inconsistent column widths.

Comment: After `Arrange` and `Measure` but before I use it as `Window.Content` and update layout I get incorrect column width values. After that all column groups have same width which is reflected in the view as well